# Python3 изменить текст label из другого потока tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, listbox

Метод run вызывается в другом потоке. Как можно изменить label из созданного потока? Как в tkinter в listbox изменить нужный мне элемент?

Например, в Delphi это делается так (насколько я помню): `listbox1.items[0]:="Абракабра";`

```
def run()
i = 0
whileTrue:
    label1["text"] = "test" + str(i)
    i+=1
    time.sleep(1)

p1 = Process(target=run,args=())
p1.start()
```

Comment: Не знаю, как быть конкретно с Python, но Tkinter использует TCL, а там потоки (package require Thread) могут изменять переменные, и на это изменение можно поставить обратный вызов с помощью `trace add variable`. Вам надо как-то наподобие делать. Поток посылает сигнал, на него отвечает функция, которая меняет `label`.

Answer (score 1):

`target=run()` - неверно: `()` не нужны, надо передавать ссылку на функцию `run`, а не вызывать ее.
Верный вариант вашего ответа такой:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label1 = Label(root,text = "label1")
label1.pack()
label2 = Label(root,text = "label2")
label2.pack()

def run(label):
    print(label)
    label['text'] = threading.current_thread().getName()

th1 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[label1])
th2 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[label2])

th1.start()
th2.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Разобрался!
Воть кому нужно пользуйтесь палки и камни прошу не кидать**

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label1 = Label(root,text = "label1")
label1.pack()
label2 = Label(root,text = "label2")
label2.pack()
lock = threading.Lock()

def run():
    print("asd")
    global label1
    with lock:
        label1['text'] =  threading.current_thread().getName()
        label2['text'] =  threading.current_thread().getName()

th1 = threading.Thread(target=run())
th2 = threading.Thread(target=run())

th1.start()
th2.start()

root.mainloop()
```